# Google maps user editable polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Using Google maps API V3, specifically using the drawing tools **(only the rectangle is enabled**) as seen here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#drawing_tools

But I have the following question,

1. Can I (if so how), by action of the user clicking a link on the same page, retrieve the lat,lng of the top left corner of the polygon and the bottom right, and send to a url, ie;

http://foo.bar/script.php?latoftopleft=17.4479216&longoftopleft=78.37720100000001&latofbotright=17.443172404867163&longofbotright=78.39395944192506

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Retrieving the Rectangle**

One way to retrieve the rectangle drawn by the user is to use [Drawing Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#drawing_events):

```js
var rectangle;
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(newRect) {
    rectangle = newRect;
});
```

Whenever a rectangle is drawn by the user, it will assign the Rectangle overlay object to the `rectangle` global variable.

**Extracting information about the Rectangle**

The [`google.maps.Rectangle` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle) has a `getBounds()` method, which returns a [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object. You can use the `getNorthEast()` and `getSouthWest()` methods to deduce the top-left and bottom-right corner coordinates.

You can bind an `onclick` event to the link. The click event handler might look something like this:

```js
function clickEventHandler(event) {
    // check if the rectangle has been assigned
    if (rectangle == undefined) {
        alert('No rectangles have been drawn yet!');
        return;
    }

    // obtain the bounds and corner coordinates of the rectangle
    var rectangleBounds = rectangle.getBounds();
    var northEast = rectangleBounds.getNorthEast();
    var southWest = rectangleBounds.getSouthWest();

    // deduce the top-left and bottom-right corner coordinates
    var topLeft = new google.maps.LatLng(northEast.lat(), southWest.lng());
    var bottomRight = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat(), northEast.lng());

    // Now that you have the coordinates, all you have to do is use an AJAX
    // technique of your choice to send the HTTP request to script.php.
    // ...
}
```

Further reading:

- [How do I bind a click to an anchor without a framework (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966160/how-do-i-bind-a-click-to-an-anchor-without-a-framework-javascript)
- [Pure Javascript send post data without a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396101/pure-javascript-send-post-data-without-a-form)

Comment: not getting the code to fire using.. <a href="#" id="link1" onclick="clickEventHandler()">call the script</a>

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors? It might also help if you posted your code using something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Ah, you are referring to the rectangle class, I was using the drawing tools, I can use the rectangle class but need the code to: 
figure out the center of the currently displayed map and place a rectangle in the middle of it upon the user clicking an outside link.

Comment: Even if you're using Drawing Tools, you can still obtain the Rectangle instance of what was drawn, by listening to the `rectanglecomplete` event provided by the API. I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: That's the ticket! Took a little sorting to get around my ignorance, lol. That works perfectly. Thanks !!