# how to dynamically create the action attribute (URL) of my html form based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry - still a beginner - How do I dynamically create action url using the input text from the user?

```
 <form name="myInstitution"  action="" method="GET">
        <div>
            <label for="names" class="bold">Institution Name</label>
            <input id="names" name="schoolName" type="text"></input>                

        </div>

        <div class="bold"></div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sbutton" name="submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Where do you want the action to come from?  `schoolName` input?

Comment: @explosion pills -- yes! exactly!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function ()
{
    var action = '';
    // compute action here...
    $(this).attr('action', action);
});
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: @sasu why is the word event in the argument for the function?

Comment: i had edited the code..thats no need..is this worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't seem to be using a javascript library, I'll copy the [bind code in pure javascript from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2967114/597122).

```
var on = (function(){
    if ("addEventListener" in window) {
        return function(target, type, listener){
            target.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
        };
    }
    else {
        return function(object, sEvent, fpNotify){
            object.attachEvent("on" + sEvent, function(){
                fpNotify(window.event);
            });
        };
    }
}());


on(document.getElementById("sbutton"), "click", function(){
    this.action = document.getElementById( "names" ).val() + ".ext";
});
```

If you were using a javascript library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), you could bind to the event handler like this:

```
$( "form[name=\"myInstitution\"]" ).on( "submit", function( e ){
    var $this = $(this),
        text  = $this.find( "input#names" ).val();

    $this.prop( "action", text + ".ext" );
});
```