# Putting two ul elements side-by-side in a menu and changing to click instead of hover

Tags: css, menu, vertical-alignment

I have this menu using just CSS and HTML. 
Some of the sub-menus are long, so I would like to sub-divide them into separate lists of up to 5 items and display them side by side instead of underneath each other.

So I've put them in a `<div>` and created 2 separate `<ul>` items. I tried to make them `display: inline` and set the maximum height of the `<div>` to `100px` but it doesn't really force the browser to put the second `<ul>` beside the first one.

```
       <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1.2 Can be long</a>
                <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.5</a></li>
                 </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.6 From here should be in 2nd col</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2.10</a></li>
                 </ul>

                </div>
            </li>
```

Full working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/nhfHw/17/
To see the issue just hover over *Item 1 > Sub Item 1.2 Can be long*

Apart from this I would like to make the menu open up the sub-levels on `click` rather than `hover` but I guess its not possible using just CSS. What is the best approach to do it in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have them sit side-by-side, use `display:inline-block` on those sub-sub `UL`s ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsTqy/)):

```
#nav ul li ul li ul 
{
  display:inline-block;
  float:none;
}
```

For binding the clicks, here is the way to do it with pure JS: [How do I bind a click to an anchor without a framework (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966160/how-do-i-bind-a-click-to-an-anchor-without-a-framework-javascript)

If you want to use jQuery, I'd recommend toggling a class and using that in the css to display/hide the navigation:

```
$('#nav li').bind('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
}
```

then in your CSS do something like:

```
#nav ul li.open ul {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `display: inline-block`, I guess I was doing it at the wrong level then! Regarding the click events, yes that function works to turn the sub-level on and off when the item is clicked, however it is not turning off any other sub-levels that would already be visible (through previous clicking) and I guess I also need to do it when something else is clicked?

Comment: I seem to have solved the click issue with this: `  <script>
         $('#nav li').bind('click', function() 
   {
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('open');
     $(this).siblings().children().removeClass('open');
     $(this).addClass('open');     
   });
      </script>`